# Count occurrences in PHP Array

Tags: php, opencart, performance

I'm playing around with opencart and trying to add a few new features to the filters functionality of the cart.

I'm wondering how do I efficiently count the number of occurrences of a given value in a multidimensional php array? For example, I'm trying to work our if all Filter->Count == 0?

```
Array
    (
    ...
    [filter] => Array
       (
       [0] => Array
       (
          [filter_id] => 109
          [name] => Boyfriends (0)
          [count] => 0
       )

       [1] => Array
       (
          [filter_id] => 114
          [name] => Daughters (0)
          [count] => 0
       )

       [2] => Array
       (
          [filter_id] => 115
          [name] => Fathers (0)
          [count] => 0
       )

       [3] => Array
       (
          [filter_id] => 108
          [name] => For Her (53)
          [count] => 53
       )
    ...
    )
...
)
```

Comment: Take a look @ http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php (at @szczepan example)

Answer (score 1):

```
$amount = 0;
foreach($array as $value) {
    if($value['count'] == 0)
        $amount++;
}
```

That would return the amount of 'counts' that equal to zero. To return the amount that aren't 0, use this:

```
$amount = 0;
foreach($array as $value) {
    if($value['count'] != 0)
        $amount++;
}
```

Then `$amount` will equal zero iff all the 'count' values are zero.